# Can’t connect to SQL Server from only one workstation

Tags: sql-server

There are 6 workstations and all but 1 can connect to SQL Server using the exact same connection string. So the SQL engine is obviously running and the issue is not centralized at server level (e.g. "Allow network connections to this server", "Maximum number of concurrent connections", "Named pipes"). Checked the firewall on the station and it's OFF at all levels. Even tried to add incoming and outgoing firewall rules for TCP 1433 and UDP 1434 with no effect. I tried to connect using the IP address of the server instead of its name in case there might be a name resolution issue between stations, but nope.

What else should I be checking on that workstation?

Thanks

Comment: Can you ping? Tracert? Telnet to port 1433 or 1434? Test-Netconnection? Is it a named instance?

Comment: What's the exact error?  Is TCP/IP enabled in the client protocols on the workstations?   Reaching, but maybe a firewall rule on the SQL Server host machine explicitly blocking the workstation?

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71789463/edit) your question to include the full and complete error message - as text. The error message may contain important information pointing to many different causes, including older/incompatible ODBC drivers, improper configuration of TLS client protocols, etc.. Also include the output of `SELECT @@VERSION` from the target SQL Server.

Comment: to add to @AlwaysLearning comment, please note if this is also On-Prem or Cloud SqlServer